# Perform action for only one clicked element of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several of these lines in my HTML:

```
    <img src="Iconos/heart.png" alt="Fave" class="fave_icon">
```

I want to change the 'src' when one of them is clicked (but ONLY on that one)

I tried this but it does not work:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.fave_icon', function (event) { 
    if ($(this).getAttribute('src') == "Iconos/heart.png")
            {
                $(this).src = "Iconos/heart_coloured.png";
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).src = "Iconos/heart.png";
            }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is the function you're in.

The clicked element is `event.target`. Replace `$(this)` with `$(event.target)` and it will work.

For the general case, where the targeted element has children, it's possible that the target of your click is a child (of `.fave_icon`). Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target the closest `.fave-icon`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.fave_icon', function(event) {
  let elem = $(event.target).closest('.fave_icon');
  if (elem.getAttribute('src') == "Iconos/heart.png") {
    elem.src = "Iconos/heart_coloured.png";
  } else {
    elem.src = "Iconos/heart.png";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it like this:

```
    <img src="Iconos/heart.png" onclick="fav(this);" alt="Fave" class="fave_icon">
```

And then

```
function fav(heart){

if (heart.getAttribute('src') == "Iconos/heart.png")
            {
                heart.src = "Iconos/heart_coloured.png";
            }
            else
            {
                heart.src = "Iconos/heart.png";
            }
```